# In LibreCalc, how to delete rows based on WHERE condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

This question told me to ask my excel question here:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90919/which-stack-exchange-site-is-best-for-microsoft-excel-questions

I'm actually using libre calculator.

I have a spreadsheet where column G is supposed to be only email addresses.  In Libre Calculator, how do I perform the equivalent of the following sql statement?

```
DELETE FROM spreadsheet WHERE g NOT LIKE '%@%'
```

This is my way of quickly deleting row with clearly erroneous emails.

Answer (score 2):

Filter and select for ColumnG contains `@` then delete rows.

Comment: Note that after you filter and delete, you can click the resize line between filtered rows, or click one column, then use Data > Filter > Reset Filter. See https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/cancel-a-filter-in-calc/42997